# JavaScript to change class on element for cascading drop-down lists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a website that uses PHP to look at various tables on a SQL Server, these tables provide the drop-down lists with their data. I wish to create a cascading drop-down list, below is the code that provides the HTML.

```
div class="col-md-4" class="form-control" id="Type">
<select>
    <?php foreach ($conn->query($sqlType) as $row){echo '<option        
class="'.$row['ShortCode'].'">'.$row['Type'].'</option>';} ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Below is the result

```
<option class=""></option>
<option class="Deal">Deal</option>
<option class="Price">Price</option>
<option class="Promo">Promo</option>
<option class="Promo">Promo</option>
<option class="LTD">Long term Deal</option>
```

On another drop-down list we wish to hide the options not selected in the first drop-down list.

```
<div class="col-md-4" class="form-control" id="Category">
  <select">
    <?php foreach ($conn->query($sqlCategory) as $row){echo '<option 
class="'.$row['Type'].' hide">'.$row['Category'].'</option>';} ?>
  </select>
</div>

<select">
```

The results are below.

```
<option class=" hide"></option>
<option class="Deal hide">Exceptional / Clearance</option>
<option class="Promo hide">Invoice</option>
<option class="Promo hide">Retro</option>
<option class="Listing hide">New</option>
<option class="Listing hide">Delisting</option>
<option class="Price hide">Increase</option>
<option class="Price hide">Decrease</option>
<option class="LTD hide">Off Invoice (ZXPN Only)</option>
<option class="LTD hide">Retro (No ZR88)</option>
```

The idea is that if for example "Listing" is selected in the first drop-down a JavaScript or JQuery script will remove the "hide" class from;

```
<option class="Listing hide">
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a "Listing" in the first drop down, but why not use value in the first dropdown, then no need to remove classes

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Type").on("change","select", function() {
    var $cat = $("#Category>select");
    $cat.find("option:gt(0)").hide(); // keep first option
    $("." + this.value, $cat).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4" class="form-control" id="Type">
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Deal">Deal</option>
    <option value="Price">Price</option>
    <option value="Promo">Promo</option>
    <option value="Listing">Listing</option>
    <option value="LTD">Long term Deal</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" class="form-control" id="Category">
  <select>
    <option class=""></option>
    <option class="Deal">Exceptional / Clearance</option>
    <option class="Promo">Invoice</option>
    <option class="Promo">Retro</option>
    <option class="Listing">New</option>
    <option class="Listing">Delisting</option>
    <option class="Price">Increase</option>
    <option class="Price">Decrease</option>
    <option class="LTD">Off Invoice (ZXPN Only)</option>
    <option class="LTD">Retro (No ZR88)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```